# Cannot start the broker and Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ to send messages between my server and client.

The following is my client side code:

```
public String sendMessage() {
    try {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:61616");
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination queue = session.createQueue("Test");
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
        msg.setText("This is a test message");
        producer.send(msg);

        producer.close();
        session.close();
        connection.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ERROR";
    }
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

Server Side Code:

```
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:61616");
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination queue = session.createQueue("Test");
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        Message message = consumer.receive(1000);

        if(message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            String text = textMessage.getText();
            System.out.println("Received: " + text);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Received: " + message);
        }

        consumer.close();
        session.close();
        connection.close();
```

I got this following error:

| ERROR | ctivemq.server]) | BrokerService                    | 324 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.14.0.SNAPSHOT | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([amq-broker, ID:activemq-56232-1449101341819-0:1], java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use)

| ERROR | ctivemq.server]) | configadmin                      | 6 - org.apache.felix.configadmin - 1.8.4 | [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory, id=826, bundle=324/mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-osgi/5.14-SNAPSHOT]: Updating configuration org.apache.activemq.server.589ab8cb-ee75-4f36-9ffe-d2c04494cf99 caused a problem: Cannot start the broker
org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException: null : Cannot start the broker
        at org.apache.activemq.osgi.ActiveMQServiceFactory.updated(ActiveMQServiceFactory.java:120)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at Proxy813ac29d_d0c7_49be_8132_e25aaca29f9e.updated(Unknown Source)[:]
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.updated(ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.java:159)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.provideConfiguration(ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.java:93)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceFactoryUpdate.provide(ConfigurationManager.java:1597)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceFactoryUpdate.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1540)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:103)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.4]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:27)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.registerConnectorMBean(BrokerService.java:2193)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startTransportConnector(BrokerService.java:2652)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startAllConnectors(BrokerService.java:2569)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartBroker(BrokerService.java:737)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startBroker(BrokerService.java:697)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:618)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.osgi.ActiveMQServiceFactory.updated(ActiveMQServiceFactory.java:116)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:33)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer.bind(TcpTransportServer.java:140)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory.doBind(TcpTransportFactory.java:62)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactorySupport.bind(TransportFactorySupport.java:40)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.createTransportServer(TransportConnector.java:315)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.getServer(TransportConnector.java:141)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.asManagedConnector(TransportConnector.java:107)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.registerConnectorMBean(BrokerService.java:2188)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)[:1.7.0_80]
        at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)[:1.7.0_80]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer.bind(TcpTransportServer.java:137)[324:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.0.SNAPSHOT]
        ... 19 more
2015-12-02 16:09:02,728 | ERROR | ctivemq.server]) | configadmin                      | 6 - org.apache.felix.configadmin - 1.8.4 | Cannot use configuration org.apache.activemq.server.589ab8cb-ee75-4f36-9ffe-d2c04494cf99 for [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory, id=829, bundle=411/mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-osgi/5.11.1]: No visibility to configuration bound to mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-osgi/5.14-SNAPSHOT

The messages are produced but at server side I got this error. I tried killing previous instance and starting a new one. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The error is telling you what's wrong, you have another broker running.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to make them work in parallel

Comment: Try using a different port

Comment: I tried using different post at server side. But it's still pointing to same port (61616).  I have the following in my activemq.xml file: 
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            
Do I have to make any changes to this file to change the port ?. Please guide me.